# Swiss/Austrian/German phone number format

Tags: regex, validation, pattern-matching

I need your help! I need a regex, that matches the following phone number formats (Germany, Austria, Switzerland). I have no idea, how to create this regex.

What I need are phone number formats as follows:

+49 (089) 1234567890

+43 (01) 1234567890

+41 (051) 1234567890

Only the mentioned country codes (+49, +43, +41) can be filled in this way (including plus sign). No 0049 or (0049) or (+49) etc.

Subsequent a space character should be between the country code and the area code. No other characters like -, /, + etc. or letters are allowed. Only space character.

The following area code must have brackets.

Subsequent a space character should also be between the area code and the phone number. No other characters like -, /, + etc. or letters are allowed. Only space character.

The phone number should be filled in its entirety (only numbers are possible and there are no spaces between the numbers).

I hope, someone can support me and my request, because I really don't know how to create this expression. I tried it and that is the result:

`[0-9]*\/*(\+49)*(\+43)*(\+41)*[ ]*(\([0-9]{3,6}\))*([ ]*[0-9]|\/|\(|\)|\-|)*`

I guess, this is totally wrong.

Best regards,
Klaus

Comment: Actually not... they start with 0 and are at least two numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the Germany, Austria, and Switzerland. First three are valid, the remaining ones are invalid for testing:

```js
const regex = /^\+4[139] \(0\d+\) \d{9,}$/;
[ '+49 (089) 1234567890',
  '+43 (01) 1234567890',
  '+41 (051) 1234567890',
  '+41 (0) 1234567890',
  '+41 (12) 1234567890',
  '+41 (051) 12',
  '+41 (051)',
  '+41 051 1234567890',
  '+41-051-1234567890',
  '+44 (051) 1234567890',
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + regex.test(str));
});
```

Output:

```
+49 (089) 1234567890 ==> true
+43 (01) 1234567890 ==> true
+41 (051) 1234567890 ==> true
+41 (0) 1234567890 ==> false
+41 (12) 1234567890 ==> false
+41 (051) 12 ==> false
+41 (051) ==> false
+41 051 1234567890 ==> false
+41-051-1234567890 ==> false
+44 (051) 1234567890 ==> false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start of string (disallow anything before)
- `\+` - literal '+'
- `4[139]` - a `41`, `43`, or `49`
- - space
- `\(0\d+\)` - a number starting with `0` and at least two digits, enclosed in parenthesis
- - space
- `\d{9,}` - a number with at least 9 digits (you can restrict both, for example `\d{9,12}` is a number with 9 to 12 digits)
- `$` - anchor at end of string (disallow anything after)

Comment: @KlausThomas: We helped you. You can help us by accepting the answer if helpful. See check mark next to answer.